# Slow lan transfer speed

Tags: networking, samba, ethernet, file-sharing, lan

I have a ubuntu box and a Windows 10 pc, both capable of gigabit ethernet. They are bottlenecked by 100mbs switches. That is not the issue though. I ran Iperf between the two and could see speeds of around 10mbs. I share("Share over Local Network) a folder on ubuntu and the transfer speed don't exeed the 2mbs. Any ideas how to fix that?